# How to remove a dynamically created button in jQuery using a Delete button

Tags: jquery

I am hoping someone can help me.

I have a form in my HTML that has two buttons.  Submit and Delete.
User input that is submitted is made into a button that when clicked, gets information from an AJAX call to an API.
Example:  User types in NEMO in the search field, and a button called NEMO is dynamically created in the html, and when user clicks on NEMO button, it would pull nemo gifs from the API. I was able to get all this to work perfectly.

HTML:

```
<form class="pixar-form" id="pixarSearch">
<div class="form-group">
<label for= "pixarInput" ></label>
<input type="text" id="pixar-input"/>
<input id="addPixar" type="button" value="Submit"/>
<input id="removePixar" type="button" value="Delete"/>
</div>
</form>
<div id = "pixarView"></div>
<div id = "buttonView"></div>
```

This is the code I am using to generate my buttons (Showing only what I think is relevant code to help answer my question at the bottom, as the AJAX call is pretty lengthy, so I did not add it here. This code is fne.:

```
var pixars = ["WALL-E", "DORY", "SULLY]

function renderButtons() {
for (var i = 0; i < pixars.length; i++) {
var a = $('<button class= "btn btn-primary">');
a.addClass("pixar");
a.attr("data-name", pixars[i]);
a.text(pixars[i]);
$("#buttonView").append(a);
}
}

$("#addPixar").on("click", function(event) {
var pixar = $("#pixar-input").val();
pixars.push(pixar);
$("#pixar-input").val(" ");
renderButtons();
}
});
```

My problem is- I cannot get the Delete button to work properly.
Here is my delete button function:

```
$("#removePixar").on("click", function() {
var pixarRemove= $(this).attr("data-name");
pixarRemove.remove();
});
```

So, for example:
I have created buttons for NEMO, BUZZ, WODY.. and I want to delete WODY because I spelled it wrong.
I click on the WODY button and hit the DELETE button and all 3 buttons would disappear instead of just the one.

I don't know how to remedy this. I've tried to .splice() the item from the Array as well, which didn't work for me either.  I feel like I'm missing a big step.
How do I get the delete button function to recognize what button I want it to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to store last clicked button in some variable and then delete that variable.

```
var deleteCandidate;
...
$("#buttonView").on("click", ".pixar", function() {
  deleteCandidate = $(this);
  ...

$("#removePixar").on("click", function() {
  deleteCandidate.remove();
```

This [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mkamilov/2Lfzu0z4/) is for working fiddle